# LWC: Iterate through a dynamic query result

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've got a result from a query that can be from a different object, or with different fields. How would I iterate through these fields, using their labels as well?

This is what I want the end result to look like:
[image: eventual output]
I've got the query working with dynamic SOQL, as below:

```
public with sharing class AccordianController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<sObject> AccordianController(id recordID,  string ParentField , string Fields, string whereClause,  string sObjectName, string sParentObjectName, string ChildParentField) {
    System.debug('recordid=' + recordID + ' parentfield=' + ParentField + ' Fields=' + Fields + ' whereClause=' + whereClause + ' sObjectName=' + sObjectName + ' sParentObjectName=' + sParentObjectName);
    string sCurrentobjectName = GetObjName(recordid);
    string queryParent='select ' + ParentField + ' from ' + sCurrentobjectName + ' where id = \''+ recordID + '\' limit 1';
    sObject ParentObj =database.query(queryParent); 
    string parentID  = String.valueof(ParentObj.get(ParentField));
    string parentObjName = GetObjName(parentID);
    string finalquery = 'select id,' + fields + ' from ' + sObjectName + ' where '+ ChildParentField +'  = \''+ parentID + '\' and ' + whereClause;
    return database.query(finalquery); 
}

public static string GetObjName(id recordid){
    Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = recordID.getSObjectType();
    String Objname = sobjectType.getDescribe().getName();
    return Objname;
}}
```

My .js file looks like this. It works when passing the properties through to the apex controller.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import ac from '@salesforce/apex/AccordianController.AccordianController';
export default class AccordianRelatedList extends LightningElement {


@api ParentField = ''
@api Fields = ''
@api whereClause = ''
@api sObjectName = ''
@api sParentObjectName = ''
@api accLabel = ''
@api ChildParentField=''
@api recordId


@wire(ac, {
            recordID: '$recordId',
            ParentField:'$ParentField',
            Fields:'$Fields',
            whereClause:'$whereClause',
            sObjectName:'$sObjectName',
            sParentObjectName:'$sParentObjectName', 
            accLabel:'$accLabel',
            ChildParentField: '$ChildParentField'})
entries;

}
```

And this is the HTML, where I'm stuck. I think everything is right up till this point, but I can't work out how to return each entry with the dynamic fields. The lines in the accordion-section are what I hard coded:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title={sObjectName}>

    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="dynamicAccordian" >
        <template for:each={entries.data} for:item="entry" for:index="indexVar" >
            <lightning-accordion-section key={entry.Id} name={entry.Id} label={entry.accLabel} >

                     ???this is where I'm stuck???

                    <p ><b>Case Number</b> : {entry.Casenumber}</p>
                    <p><b>Subject</b> : {entry.Subject}</p>
                    <p><b>Status</b> : {entry.Status}</p>

            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </template>
    </lightning-accordion>

</lightning-card>
</template>
```

The other thing I'm trying to do is take a specific field specified in accLabel and use it as the label of each accordion section.

Thanks

Comment: Try displaying without accordion. Maybe Accordion tag doesn't support that way.

Comment: Also instead of 'for:each' use 'Iterator'